# Perform operation based on matching column values from another table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to write two queries for a postgres database, but my skills are still a bit too low and I don't have quite clear how to do that.
I have three tables, with data related to visits to a web platform and the edits made by users.
The first one contains the daily visits for each page (pageid) on the platform.

```
Table 1
pageid |    date   | visits
---------------------------
pageid1| 01-01-2016|   2   
pageid1| 02-01-2016|   1   
pageid1| 03-01-2016|   3    
pageid1| 04-01-2016|   4
pageid1| 05-01-2016|   3
pageid1| 06-01-2016|   2
...
pageid1| 01-02-2016|   4
...
pageid2| 01-01-2016|   5
...
```

The second one contains the edits made to each page, there can be more than one edit per day (currently the table has a timestamp, but I can easily convert that into a date).

```
Table 2
 pageid|    date   | content
-----------------------------
pageid1| 01-01-2016|   a   
pageid1| 01-01-2016|   b   
pageid1| 03-01-2016|   c    
pageid1| 03-01-2016|   c    
pageid1| 03-01-2016|   e    
pageid1| 04-01-2016|   e    
pageid1| 04-01-2016|   c    
pageid1| 05-01-2016|   e    
pageid1| 06-01-2016|   f    
...
```

The third table contains only the edits made to some elements that are in the pages. There may be more than one element per page.

```
Table 3
 pageid|  page_ref  |    date   | content_ref
---------------------------------------------
pageid1| page_ref_1 | 01-01-2016|   a   
pageid1| page_ref_1 | 03-01-2016|   b   
pageid1| page_ref_2 | 03-01-2016|   c    
pageid1| page_ref_2 | 05-01-2016|   c    
pageid1| page_ref_2 | 06-01-2016|   c    
pageid1| page_ref_3 | 02-01-2016|   c    
pageid1| page_ref_3 | 07-03-2016|   c    
pageid1| page_ref_3 | 03-04-2016|   c    
...
```

What I would like to achieve with my queries is:

1. For each element in a page (page_ref), compute the number of page **visits** between each edit and the previous one.
2. For each element in a page (page_ref), compute the number of page **edits** between each edit and the previous one.

Eventually, I would like to have a table like this:

```
Table 4
 pageid|  page_ref  |    date   | content_ref | visit_no | edit_no
-------------------------------------------------------------------
pageid1| page_ref_1 | 01-01-2016|   a         |    NA    |    NA
pageid1| page_ref_1 | 03-01-2016|   b         |     6    |     4
pageid1| page_ref_2 | 03-01-2016|   c         |    NA    |     NA
pageid1| page_ref_2 | 05-01-2016|   c         |    10    |     6
pageid1| page_ref_2 | 06-01-2016|   c         |    5     |     2  
...
```

I hope what I ask is clear, many thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Not yet, actually. I will try something out and update the post.